# Threading in python: daemon.start() eat 20% of my crawler time. Why?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm looking around about threading to develop cool easy web crawler, but it works so slowly.

Here is a fragment of code I found in [ibm library](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/):

```
    urls = [] # huge list of urls
    in_queue = Queue.Queue()
    out_queue = Queue.Queue()

    pool = ActivePool()
    s = threading.Semaphore(semaphore)

    for url in urls[:slice_size]:
            in_queue.put(url)
            t = ThreadUrl(pool, s, url, in_queue, out_queue)
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()

    counter = slice_size
    while not in_queue.empty() or not out_queue.empty():
          speed_new_daemon = time.time()
          url = urls[counter]
          in_queue.put(url)
          t = ThreadUrl(pool, s, url, in_queue, out_queue)
          t.setDaemon(True)

          t.start()        # <------ why 20% of all time I lose here?

          counter += 1
          speed_new_daemon = time.time() - speed_new_daemon

          speed_parser = time.time()
          result = out_queue.get()
          my_parser(result)
          speed_parser = time.time() - speed_parser

          # speed_parser only 80%, when speed_new_daemon takes 20%...
    in_queue.join()
```

Comment: Multithreaded code is hard to profile. How did you measure this?

Comment: This is not the code from the linked document.

Comment: Also, the line your title refers to does not exist in either your source or IBM's.

Comment: Can you explain why you made all the bizarre changes from the IBM source? If you tell us what all your new code is _supposed_ to be doing, you might get better answers than if you make us guess (because honestly, I can't tell what you were even attempting).

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) if you plan on doing any sort of web scraping.

Answer (score 4):

The IBM document you quoted starts 5 threads:

```
#spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance 
for i in range(5):
  t = ThreadUrl(queue)
  t.setDaemon(True)
  t.start()
```

Your code is completely different. First it creates a pool of one thread per URL:

```
for url in urls[:slice_size]:
    in_queue.put(url)
    t = ThreadUrl(pool, s, url, in_queue, out_queue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

And then it goes on creating new threads every time through the main loop:

```
while not queue.empty() or not out_queue.empty():
      speed_start_new_daemon = time.time()
      url = urls[counter]
      in_queue.put(url)
      t = ThreadUrl(pool, s, url, in_queue, out_queue)
      t.setDaemon(True)
```

So eventually, you're going to have a ton of threads. With all those threads fighting over only a few cores, each thread is going to spend most of its time waiting around. On top of that, you're eventually going to stress out the scheduler, so your CPU will spend a good chunk of its time just trying to figure out how to run your threads.

Meanwhile, starting 1000 threads may not take that much CPU time, but downloading 1000 URLs doesn't take much CPU time either (it's I/O-bound, not processor-bound), so… where did you expect the CPU usage to be concentrated?

Comment: I expect in my_parser(result), but it take only 80% of free time. me need 99%

Comment: Well, you can't ever have 100% of the CPU unless you write OS-less embedded code, and you certainly can't have 100% of the CPU if you're using OS threads. Besides, using more CPU isn't an advantage, it's a _cost_—if it actually makes your code run faster, that's a good tradeoff, but just using it for the sake of using it is silly. At any rate, my answer already explains what your problem is. Fix it, and your code will go much faster.